# MySQL Trigger doesn't work

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a little problem with my trigger. 
i created a trigger:

```
BEGIN 

IF((SELECT `Wert` 
    FROM parameter_history 
    WHERE `BusNr` = NEW.BusNr AND `MesswertNr` = NEW.MesswertNr 
    ORDER BY `Timestamp` DESC LIMIT 1) != NEW.Value) 


THEN 
    INSERT INTO parameter_history (`BusNr`, `MesswertNr`, `Value`) 
    VALUES (NEW.BusNr, NEW.MesswertNr, NEW.Value); 
END IF; 

END
```

The event of the trigger is after an update. 
if there is already a `New.Value` it works really good. 
but if there is no `New.Value` in my database it doesn't work and i don't know why. 
The problem is, that i can`t get a value back from "NEW.Value" when there is actually no entry in my table. 
With a MySQL-Programm i got "0 Rows found" and i want to fix this problem.

Can anybody help me?

kind regards

Comment: It would be better if you added the whole trigger code: `CREATE TRIGGER ...`

Comment: i created the trigger by an external programm - heidisql

Comment: You can run `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name` command to get whole trigger code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it works if there is already a NEW.value look at your statement,

```
    IF((select x) != NEW.Value)  // select x only when it does not equal 
//what the current value of New.Value is.

THEN  // preform my insert statement. 
    INSERT INTO parameter_history (`BusNr`, `MesswertNr`, `Value`) 
    VALUES (NEW.BusNr, NEW.MesswertNr, NEW.Value); 

END IF;
```

Now consider the case that New.Value does not exist or is empty(null), you are running, select x only when it does not equal ???? .

You are going to get 0 rows returned.

I'm not quite sure what you're building but why not use a default value for New.Value then run a procedure to update it whenever you need, then your trigger will execute after update on a non empty field?